# Detecting UIControlEventTouchUpInside and deleting UITableViewCell gesture

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem when detecting a UIControlEventTouchUpInside of a UIButton that is inside an UITableViewCell. The app implements the edit delegate method of the UITableView class in order to allow the user delete cells.

When I tap the button, it triggers the selector and does what it has to do (correct behavior). The problem is when I do the gesture of deleting a cell beginning in the same location of the button. Both edit delegate method and the selector assigned to the button are triggered. Therefore, the behavior isn't the expected because the cell is moved, and the button logic is also executed. Is there any way to detect if the user has done a deleting gesture, but not a tap gesture?

Here is my implementation, hope this will help.

Implementation of edit delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here the UIButton implementation:

```
UIButton *videoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    videoButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[videoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(videoButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:videoButton];
```

and the selector method implementation:

```
- (void)videoButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
   (some domain logic...)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `UIControlEventTouchDragInside` Event to videoButton so you can check if user dragged or just tapped.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you start editing your cell (swipe) the cell changes its editing state to YES, so you can check the editing mode of your cell on the **videoButtonTapped:** method, so that if cell is in editing mode, just do nothing.